# iOS: Changing or swap positions of subString by index in NSMutableString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsmutablestring

I'm trying to change or swap position of substring. I know you can do that with NSMutableArray the following way:

```
[myMutableArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:(20) withObjectAtIndex:30];
```

Any of you knows if theres something similar for NSMutableString ?

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you looked at the documentation for `NSString`?  Are you aware of basic algorithms, such as swapping the values of 2 array elements?  Do you really need Apple to write it for you?

Answer (score 0):

Something similar with NSMutableString would be using deleteCharacters(in:) and insert(at:) which isn't quite as lightweight. For the sake of an example (I don't know Obj-C but in Swift), this would like something like:

```
var myTestString: NSMutableString = "itIsATestString"
let mySubStringRange = myTestString.range(of: "Test")
myTestString.deleteCharacters(in:mySubStringRange)
myTestString.insert("Test", at: 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices:

```
theChar = [ myString characterAtIndex:4 ];
newString = [ NSString stringWithCharacters:&theChar length:1 ];
```

or, avoiding the `characterAtIndex`: alltogether, but still using one selected character:

```
newString = [ myString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange( 4, 1 ) ];
```